# YouTube Stream and Display Date and Time on the stream

Tags: raspivid, youtube

I'm streaming to YouTube with a Raspberry Pi. I would like to to display the date and time in the video. Is this possible?

I'm using the terminal command:

```
raspivid -o - -n -t 0 -vf -hf -br 50 -fps 30 -b 6000000 | avconv -re -ar 44100 -ac 2 -acodec pcm_s16le -f s16le -ac 2 -i /dev/zero -f h264 -i - -vcodec copy -acodec aac -ab 128k -g 50 -strict experimental -f flv rtmp://a.rtmp.youtube.com/live2/###########
```

Answer (score 2):

Try the annotate (-a) option, for example:

```
raspivid -a 12
```

Shows date and time. There are also options to change the formatting of date and time.

See [camera documentation](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/raspbian/applications/camera.md) for detailed information.